# How can I set up a port forward from my client computer's shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port-forwarding

I notice that my bittorrent client is capable of automatically setting up port forwards with my router, and I want to know if I can do the same in a shell script. The reason is, that since my router is stupid and won't let me keep static IP addresses (it seems they forced a DHCP refresh every week to make me want to pay for a more expensive model which doesn't), I need to get my computer to change the port forward to follow my computer's changing internal network IP address. I have a couple of port forward manually entered into my router settings for web interfaces to bittorrent etc, but of course these have a good chance of being invalidated at each DHCP refresh cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're talking UPnP here.

First, why not just set a static IP address in your computer?  The router doesn't need to know or care about that and it will stop your IP changing.

Otherwise, take a look at the MiniUPNP project: http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/

Comment: My computer is a laptop... Is there way that I can give it a static IP for only my home network? I've tried to do a similar thing in the past in windows, and found that the static IP settings were considered global and could not be made network dependent.

Comment: Windows still hasn't got its wireless settings sorted properly has it?  In other operating systems the IP settings are bound to the wireless profile not the interface card :/  There are ways around it with batch files to switch networking settings for you: http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Switch-Network-Settings-Batch-Files_t9048.html but it's not wonderful.

Comment: Ah I see. I just poked around with the settings and managed to get a static IP for just that network on Ubuntu. Since Windows wouldn't do it I just assumed it was a hardware limitation. Thanks.